# NodeJS: uploads big files, but server is falling on small ones

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This is the part of the code:

```
app.all("/upload_document", async(req, res, body) => {

    let result = {};

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {

        let oldpath = files.file[0].filepath;
        do
        {
            let a = new Uint8Array(16);
            crypto.getRandomValues(a);
            var newname = Array.from(a, dec2hex).join('');
            var newpath = __dirname + '/public/files/' + newname;
        }
        while (fs.existsSync(newpath));

        fs.copyFileSync(oldpath, newpath);
        fs.unlinkSync(oldpath);

        var id = fields.id[0];
        var name = fields.name[0];
        var description = fields.description[0];

        var type = files.file[0].mimetype;
        var filename = files.file[0].originalFilename;

        let new_download_document = {"name": filename,
                                    "real_name": newname,
                                    "type": type};

        console.log(0, newname);

        await mongoClient.connect();

        console.log(1, newname);

        const db = mongoClient.db("neotmpp");
        const collection = await db.collection("download_documents");
        const download_documents = await collection.find({}).toArray();

        console.log(2, newname);

        var keys = [];
        Object.keys(download_documents[0]).forEach((key) => {
            if (isNaN(key)) return;
            let key_int = parseInt(key, 10);
            keys.push(key_int);
        });

        console.log(3, newname);

        let document_id = Math.max(...keys)+1;

        console.log(4, newname);

        download_documents[0][document_id] = new_download_document;

        console.log(4.5, newname);

        //console.log(download_documents);
        //console.log(collection);
        await collection.replaceOne({}, download_documents[0]);
```

I have a MongoDB collection with the only one document:

```
7: Object
    name: "W10DigitalActivation.exe"
    real_name: "a94b3004e50af41fcd7c3a72d2599781"
    type: "application/x-msdownload"

8: Object
    name: "pspad506_x64_setup.exe"
    real_name: "b458b3ed0c9b8d93bff8912f13756d53"
    type: "application/x-msdownload"

9: Object
    name: "kkkkkkkkkkUntitled.png"
    real_name: "daca5f507e79571c6692f436964a5343"
    type: "image/png"

_id: 65cb634d6631a32a4d781f4d
```

I uploads big files and makes a records in the document. It works OK with big files, but when i trying to upload small ones, the server crashes with the error:

```
0 066335facbcab8a26f77c874417ff2ef
1 066335facbcab8a26f77c874417ff2ef
2 066335facbcab8a26f77c874417ff2ef
3 066335facbcab8a26f77c874417ff2ef
4 066335facbcab8a26f77c874417ff2ef
4.5 066335facbcab8a26f77c874417ff2ef
D:\web3\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:24
            throw new error_1.MongoNotConnectedError('Client must be connected before running operations');
                  ^

MongoNotConnectedError: Client must be connected before running operations
    at executeOperationAsync (D:\web3\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:24:19)
    at D:\web3\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:45
    at maybeCallback (D:\web3\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:338:21)
    at executeOperation (D:\web3\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\execute_operation.js:12:38)
    at Collection.replaceOne (D:\web3\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:173:57)
    at D:\web3\server\app.js:639:26
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v20.11.0
```

What's wrong?

I want to work with small files as good as with big ones.

Comment: Seems an async problem